# Testing struts 2 actions

Tags: java, testing, struts

Guys what is the best way to test struts actions? Is there any framework someone can recommend?
I just recently started working with struts, I used to use mockito for spring mvc testing, but I can't find any good source online, most of them are way too outdated.

Comment: `Struts 2` comes up with a JUnit plugin library that makes it easier to develop unit tests for testing your Struts 2 action classes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider for each config file you want to add.
2. Override the StrutsTestCase setUp method.
3. If you have multiple actions in your project, create a base test class that extends StrutsTestCase and just have all your action tests extend that.

**Refer to this sample implementation:**

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    List<ContainerProvider> providers = super.configurationManager.getContainerProviders();
    //make one of these for each config file you want to add
    StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider newConfig = new StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml", true, super.servletContext);
    providers.add(newConfig);
    super.configurationManager.reload();
}
```

Comment: Any specific annotation/inheritance for the test class?

Comment: Nope. Not needed!

Comment: hi man, thank you for the help, just one more thing, how do I actually do the action testing after setting up my configuration?